# How to make keep track of clicks and not click the same place twice

Tags: python, click, mouse, pyautogui

Here is my code:

```
while (1):
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(200,150,1600,800))
    width, height = pic.size
    for x in range (0,width,1):
    
        for y in range (0,height,1):

            r,g,b = pic.getpixel((x,y))
            if r == 71 and g == 38:

                click(x+200, y+150)
                
                time.sleep(0.5)
               
                if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('kalk.png', grayscale=True,confidence=0.8) != None: 
                    click(1111, 906)
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    click(1155, 165)
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    click(1342, 994)
                    pyautogui.press('a')
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    pyautogui.press('a')
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    pyautogui.press('a')
                else: 
                    pyautogui.press('ctrl')
                    continue
```

I want to make sure that my code cannot click the same place twice and instead remember where it has clicked and not click the same place a second time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Because all of your coordinate pairs can be expressed as a tuple, you can use a `set` to keep track of where has been clicked, and only click somewhere that hasn't already been clicked:

```
while(1):
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(200,150,1600,800))
    width, height = pic.size
    clicked = set() # Create set
    for x in range (0,width,1):
        for y in range (0,height,1):
            r,g,b = pic.getpixel((x,y))
            if r == 71 and g == 38 and (x, y) not in clicked:  # Check if coordinates already clicked
                clicked.add((x, y))  # Mark coordinates as clicked
                click(x+200, y+150)
                
                ...
```